# Просмотр интернет-страниц с Ubuntu Server

Tags: ubuntu

Возможно ли просматривать интернет-страницы с Ubuntu Server? Как это сделать? Естественно иксов нет.

Answer (score 1):

Задача стоит неконкретно. Можно вообще извернуться и использовать X11 Forwarding - это когда приложение на сервере, а отображение идет на Ваш терминал с графическим сервером. При этом наличие X11 и средств вывода на сервере необязательно. Я таким образом запускал Dwarf Fortress и многое другое :-)

Еще можно использовать текстовые браузеры - links и lynx.

Answer (score 0):

Конечно![Lynx](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lynx) вам в помощь.